# Read a txt file by URL link in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, readfile

I have a txt file in the following URL path:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz9qp06fykz4otw/Counter.txt

I wana read it into MATLAB. This file contains only an integer value. I used `fopen()` function, but it gives me error:

> The file name contains characters that are not contained in the filesystem encoding.  Certain operations may not work as expected.

Then, I used `webread()` and `urlread()`, but a big file is generating and not working as expected.

Is there any suggestion to how to read a simple value from an URL link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the url https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz9qp06fykz4otw/Counter.txt refers to the dropbox page and not the file. If you add `?dl=1` at the end of the link, then it will refer to the file instead. e.g.

```
data = urlread('https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz9qp06fykz4otw/Counter.txt?dl=1')

data =

    '100'
```